# How to predict probabilities for a target variable?

Tags: machine-learning, probability

I came across a [kaggle challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/march-machine-learning-mania-2016/data) where you have to predict the probabilities for all matchups in a basketball tournament. I was already working with classification and regression algorithms like SVM, Naive Bayes, Random Forests, Nerual Networks etc. Therefore I used R and the caret package. But as the result you always get the final classificated class without the respective probability. E.g. it would either classify 1 if the team home wins and 0 when the team away wins. How can you predict the respective probability that you can say team home has a 82% chance to win?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you use the predict() function in R. You can specify the output you want. For example `type="response"` or `type="prob"`. Type `"prob"` and/or `"raw"` (depending on the model) will output class probability.

Example:

```
# Predicting class
pred_class <- predict(model, test_set, type="response")
# Predicting probability of class
pred_prob <- predict(model, test_set, type="prob")
```

Edit:
Arguments in the predict.train {caret} (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/caret/docs/predict.train):

type
either "raw" or "prob", for the number/class predictions or class probabilities, respectively. Class probabilities are not available for all classification models